# Opening Notepad.exe using Tkinter (threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to thread using `tkinter` and running into issues. My main plan is to eventually open a program and utilize hotkeys to navigate through the menus of said program to automate a recursive process I'm doing. I understand this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but there are reasons why this is the only available approach.

I'm trying at the moment to simply write a notepad version of the code that will copy the textbox user entry strings and type them into notepad. I've heard I will need to use threading to do my final project, but clearly I'm not doing something correctly as once notepad opens the program doesn't proceed. Below is the code:

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

"""Sleep function"""
def SleepSec(var):
     time.sleep(var)


"""Hotkey function runs hotkeys to take measurement"""
def Notepad_Test():
     mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
     key = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

     """Open notepad program"""
     subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'],shell=True)
     SleepSec(5)
     """Click on program window"""
     mouse.position = (400,400)
     mouse.click(pynput.mouse.Button.left, 1)

     """Sorting variables from inputs"""
     intervalEntry = E1.get() #Interval time
     dataEntry = dropVar.get() #RAW or Radiometric data
     pathEntry = E2.get() #Path file
     filenameEntry = E3.get() #filename
     startNumEntry = E4.get() #Starting measurement number
     countEntry = E5.get() #Number of measurements to take
     commentEntry = E6.get() #Comments about measurement

     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(intervalEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(dataEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(pathEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(filenameEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(startNumEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(countEntry)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter.value)
     SleepSec(1)
     key.type(commentEntry)
     SleepSec(1)

"""Create a GUI"""
root = Tk()

root.title('Measurement')

dropVar = StringVar(root)

options = [
     "RAW",
     "Radiometric"
]

dropVar.set(options[0])

"""Labels and entries for desired measurement parameters"""
L1 = Label(root, text = "Measurement Interval").grid(row = 0)
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E1.insert(10,"1")
E1.grid(row=0,column=1)

L2 = Label(root, text = "Pathname").grid(row = 1)
E2 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E2.insert(10,"C:/Users/ASD User/Documents/ASD_data/test")
E2.grid(row=1,column=1)

L3 = Label(root, text = "Filename").grid(row = 2)
E3 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E3.insert(10,"DefaultFilename")
E3.grid(row=2,column=1)

L4 = Label(root, text = "Measurement #").grid(row = 3)
E4 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E4.insert(10,"0")
E4.grid(row=3,column=1)

L5 = Label(root, text = "Number of files to save").grid(row = 4)
E5 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E5.insert(10,"30")
E5.grid(row=4,column=1)

L6 = Label(root, text = "Comment").grid(row = 5)
E6 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
E6.insert(10,"Comment here")
E6.grid(row=5,column=1)

O1 = OptionMenu(root, dropVar, *options).grid(row = 6)

"""Buttons for running measurement and quitting"""
B1 = Button(root,
          text = 'Quit',
          command = root.quit).grid(row = 7,
                                   column = 0,
                                   sticky=W,
                                   pady=4)

B2 = Button(root,
          text = "Measure", command= lambda: threading.Thread(target = Notepad_Test).start()).grid(row=7,
                                                       column=1,
                                                       sticky=W,
                                                       pady=4)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
subprocess.call
```

Is a [blocking function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) because it waits for it to finish which in this case means that it waits until you close notepad before proceeding on with the automation.

You probably want to use

```py
subprocess.Popen
```

because it *Executes a child program in a new process*, meaning that it will open notepad and then continue on with the automation.

For your case you really just need to change `call` to `Popen`, that is literally the only change required.

Useful:

- [`subprocess.Popen` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfectly thank you for all the information. Do you know if there ever is a reason to call a program vs. using Popen?

Comment: @Bear There is no reason to use `call` because it is an [older API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api), it says there: _You can now use run() in many cases, but lots of existing code calls these functions._ So really you probably would want to use `run`. When? [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) it says that _The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly._ 1/2

Comment: And this case is more advanced since blocking is not wanted. Also seemingly `run` itself uses `Popen` anyways since it is [_The underlying process creation and management in this module_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), so really `Popen` can be used in any case, but it is just recommended to use `run` (the "newer" `call`) whenever possible. For more detailed info I suggest that you read the documentation. It also would be great if you could accept the answer as correct. Thanks! 2/2

Comment: Great information. Thank you so much!